# axios in react with self signed certificate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using a backend developed in java with a ssl self  signed certificate and  exposing in 8443, but when I try to consuime in react with axios im getting and error with the certificate.
There is  a way to skip ssl validation in react to access a self signed certificate without a problem ?
Im using react 17 webpack 5.69.1
Here is my react implementation:

```
export const HOST_API = 'https://192.168.1.9:8443';
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
 
  baseURL: HOST_API,
});
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => Promise.reject((error.response && error.response.data) || 'Something went wrong')
);
export default axiosInstance;
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I cannot find a solution yet